# Collapse view animation objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

(Please find the sample image at the bottom)
When top upper view comes, the remaining 5 views collapse downside and visible only 4 at last & make space for it using animation my code is this but i cant understand how to do it.

```
-(void) tapme:(NSTimer *)timer{

    if (i<=5) {
        NSLog(@"%ld",i);
        y = y - 35;
        if (y % 2 == 0) {
            UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-150, y, 150, 34)];
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
            v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            [self.view addSubview:v];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
                v.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-75, y, 150, 34);
            }];
        }
        else{
            UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, y, 150, 34)];
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
            v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            [self.view addSubview:v];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
                v.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-75, y, 150, 34);
            }];
        }
         i++;
    }
    else{

        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-150, y, 150, 34)];
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
            v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            [self.view addSubview:v];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
                v.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-75, y, 150, 34);
            }];
            i++;
        }
        else{
            UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, y, 150, 34)];
            v.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
            v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
            [self.view addSubview:v];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
                v.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-75, y, 150, 34);
            }];
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: dynamic view came from both side]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. I modified your code as follows.

- I removed duplicate code in several places. The four blocks you had were mostly identical.
- I added code to keep track of the views by using the `tag` property. Setting the `tag` will let you get hold of the view later, without need for storing a reference to the view. Instead use `UIView`  method `viewWithTag:`.
- I added code to move down the previous 5 blocks when there are 5 or more blocks and also fade out the bottom block at the same time.
- I added a completion block on the animation to remove the faded out block when animation is done.

There are still room for improvements, but I hope you understand how to go on from here.

```
-(IBAction)tapme:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%ld",i);

    if (i < 5)
        y = y - 35;

    CGFloat x = i % 2 == 0 ? -150.0 : self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 150, 34)];
    v.tag = i + 100;
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 7;
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v];

    __block UIView *bottomView = nil;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
        v.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x-75, y, 150, 34);

        // If we have 5 blocks then we move them down and fade out the bottom one
        if (i >= 5) {
            for (NSInteger n = i - 1; n > i - 6; --n) {
                UIView *oldView = [self.view viewWithTag:n + 100];
                CGRect frame = oldView.frame;
                frame.origin.y += 35;
                oldView.frame = frame;
            }
            bottomView = [self.view viewWithTag:i - 5 + 100];
            bottomView.alpha = 0.0;
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        // Remove the bottom block after animation finished
        if (bottomView != nil)
            [bottomView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Thankss bro its awesome . . . . :)